# firebase firestore http function

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angular6, google-cloud-functions

I am calling a firebase firestore http function from my angular app, but it always returns an error.

service.ts

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private afs: AngularFirestore,
 private fns: AngularFireFunctions, private afstorage: AngularFireStorage) { }
call(url: string) {

this.fns.httpsCallable(url)({ text: 'some-data' })
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(resp => {
    console.log({ resp });
  }, err => {
    console.log({ error: err });
  });

}
```

index.ts

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp()
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

export const hello = functions.region('asia- 
northeast1').https.onRequest((data, context) => {
    cors(data, context, () => { '' })
    console.log('execution started');
    console.log('data', data);
    return;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're attempting to use the `onRequest` function trigger, which requires a callback with a response and request parameters. You'll need to send something back to the client using `response.send()`.

```
functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send('Success!');
});
```

Alternatively, the structure you are using works with `https.onCall()`

Documentation for `onRequest`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events
Documentation for `onCall`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: how can i write the function with onCall request?can you please explain it

Comment: The second link Richard gave shows the documentation on creating Callable functions.

Comment: i write a function using the example given in the link,it always giving an error of  
error: {status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT", message: "Bad Request"}
,   what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the angular implementation, but with the firebase client SDK, you'd execute a callable function as follows: `firebase.functions().httpsCallable('functionName')(requestData).then(...)`